# AntD - how to use dark theme for a single component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

So the component lib has a dark theme.
I would like to use dark style only for a single component, say a `Popover`. All the rest sd remain default.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: embed it into an additional theme provider

Comment: try passig style={{background: '#ddd'}} to the pop over component

Answer (score 1):

you could use less `reference import` feature for theming single component. Sudo code would be something like

```
@import (reference) "@ant-design/dark-theme"

.my-popover {
  &:extend(@popover-prefix-cls all);
}
```

you can find the class name `@popover-prefix-cls` by going into [individual components styles](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/popover/style/index.less#L4) file and checking the class

References: https://css-tricks.com/reference-imports-in-less-are-kinda-cool/