# Dark theme for a specific Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am trying to use Ant Design dark theme for single functional component in react (This component is an individual react page, with a specific route, which is called in App.tsx file).

So I am importing a separate .less file for my component, and this styling file contains `@import '~antd/dist/antd.dark.less';` at the start. Now dark theme is available in my component. But this dark theme also gets rendered to other components in the project(despite having different routes and different .less files) that uses ant design components.

What is the ideal way to implement dark theme for a specific component in react antd?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895977/antd-how-to-use-dark-theme-for-a-single-component

Comment: Ive gone through this, but I want to apply the dark theme to only one single page (component) in react. And not to individual components.

Comment: Can you use classes instead of `less` variables?

Comment: In this case, I will suggest looking at styled-component, This library can help you. You need to pass a prop called theme to component and based on theme render your styled component. https://dev.to/aromanarguello/how-to-use-themes-in-styled-components-49h